# How to bypass function for element with specify class and two conditions with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's hard to say in couple wors in title... So i have this code:

```
var class_main_content = $('.main_content ul').attr('class');
var xml_element_name = $(xml).find(class_main_content)[0].nodeName.toLowerCase();
var no_option = $('.no_option').attr('class');
if ((class_main_content) == xml_element_name){
   ...
}
else if ($(class_main_content) == (no_option)){
   ...
}
```

and i have first condition with some actions - every things fine, next i have second condition which first condition is also performs, but i need to do something for element with class `.no_option`. The problem grows when this element have two class from first condition and second. How to pass by first condition and do something for second? :)

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking.

Comment: i have 2 conditions and one html element, both of it performs, but there is one moment where this element recive class no_option wchih is perform from first condition, so  i need to block function from first condition when this element has class no_option

Comment: so add to the first if another check that looks at that state.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than getting the `class` attribute and comparing it against things, why not use the [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) JQuery function:

```
var main_content=$('.main_content ul');
if(main_content.hasClass('something')) {
    do_something();
}
if(main_content.hasClass('no_option')) {
    do_something_else();
}
```

You can of course do the reverse test:

```
if(!main_content.hasClass('no_option')) ...
```

Comment: as you can see this elements and thoes classes is generating dinamicly, i can't set 120 conditions for 120 classes :D

Comment: If you need 120 different behaviours then you'll need 120 conditions! Anyway, you can of course pass a variable to `hasClass` with the class name in, if the precise name is not available until runtime.

Comment: ooo, that may can help, i should try this